# Redirect all traffic to SSL except one location

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I have an nginx server running serving my website. All the connections are redirected to SSL for security reasons.

However, I was desperately looking how to exclude one location from this redirect. I already tried rewrite, redirect, proxy_pass etc. but it doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to (301 or 302) redirect my site, I only want SSL to be optional. The location various types of files (js, php, html).

For example

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com
    root /var/www/example;

    location /unsafe {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    # other rules...
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com
    root /var/www/example;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # other rules...
}
```

does not work.

I also tried using `redirect` or `rewrite` instead of `try_files`, but no luck at all. The thing is, I don't want to the traffic to be redirected, rewritten or proxy'd, I only want nginx to pass all requests on example.com/unsafe

All I get is a bunch of 404's ands 502's.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should have separate server blocks for the normal http connections (on port 80) and the https SSL connections (on port 443).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-domain.com
    root /var/www/;

    location /unsafe {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # your other rules...
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name your-domain.com
    root /var/www/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # your other rules...
}
```

#### Amended code:

If you want all files on your site to use https connections (SSL, port 443) **EXCEPT** those files inside the */unsafe* directory, this is what your server blocks should look like:

```
# This server block handles all requests on port 80 and serves only files inside
# the /unsafe directory. Everything else is redirected to an SSL connection on
# port 443.

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-domain.com
    root /var/www/;

    # only serve requests to files in the /unsafe directory
    location /unsafe {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # all other locations redirect to https connection
    location / {
        return 301 https://your-domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    # this location block proxies requests for PHP files to
    # your fcgi php processor
    location ~ /unsafe/.*\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        # your fcgi rules here...
    }

    # your other rules...
}


# This server block handles all SSL (port 443) connections.

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name your-domain.com
    root /var/www/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # this location block proxies requests for PHP files to
    # your fcgi php processor
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        # your fcgi rules here...
    }

    # your other rules...
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry - I wasn't clear enough. I already did that, but the error lies in the `location` settings for port 80 I assume

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want the SSL connection to be optional, then your server block can listen for both 90 and 443 and the location rules will work for both. But if you want files under a certain directory (for exmaple, "/unsafe") to be served by normal http connections with no SSL, then under your server block listening on port 80 you can have a location rule matching the directory and you will have to redirect all other connections to use https (port 443).

Comment: I updated my initial question to better highlight what I try to do!

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear: You say, "All the connections are redirected to SSL for security reasons" but you also say, "I don't want to (301 or 302) redirect my site, I only want SSL to be optional" -- the two are contradictory. I've add server block examples to handle what I think you're trying to do, but I'm still not sure what exactly what you are aiming at.

Comment: okay, thank you. I need to wait until early in the morning to apply the settings, otherwise there is too much traffic on the server. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: @kchaen I tried your settings and the redirections didn't work. I tried using both `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` (redirects everything to SSL) and `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` (404 error) inside `location /unsafe`

Comment: Can you post your server blocks for both port 80 and SSL port 443?